# Supersymmetry infinitesimal variation

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, superalgebra

In [Wess & Bagger](https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691025308/supersymmetry-and-supergravity), chapter 3, the infinitesimal supersymmetric transformation is defined as: $$ \delta_\xi \psi = i\sqrt{2} \ \sigma^m \bar{\xi}\partial_m A + \sqrt{2} \ \xi F$$ and $$\delta_\xi A = \sqrt{2} \ \xi \psi$$ and an important exercise claims that $$ \delta_\eta \delta_\xi \psi = -2i\eta \sigma^m\bar{\xi}\partial_m\psi - i[\sigma^n\bar{\sigma}^m\partial_m\psi](\eta\sigma^n\bar{\xi}) + \sqrt{2} \xi \delta_\eta F $$ The first and last term is easily found, since it comes from the variation of $A$ and $F$ in the first expression above. Where does the middle term come from? Is it due to commutation like $[\delta,\partial]$?

Comment: Have you antisymmetrized w.r.t. the two fermionic parameters?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, do you mean to do $(\delta_\xi \delta_\eta - \delta_\eta \delta_\xi )\psi$?

Comment: Your δs are bosonic, but your  ξ and  η are fermionic, so odd under interchange. Not nice language.

Answer (score 2):

The first *and the second* term comes from $\delta_{\eta}A$. It is

$$
i\sqrt{2}\sigma^m_{\alpha\dot\alpha}\bar\xi^{\dot\alpha}\partial_m(\sqrt{2}\eta^{\beta}\psi_{\beta})
$$

You need to uses the gamma matrix identity:

$$
\delta^{\alpha}_{\beta}\delta^{\dot\alpha}_{\dot\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{\alpha\dot\alpha}_m\sigma^m_{\beta\dot\beta}
$$

in order to compare with the answer.